# Подключение к удаленной виртуальной машине KVM

Tags: виртуальная-машина, виртуализация, kvm, centos7

Здравствуйте. Установил Centos 7. Подключился к ней по ssh. Поставил QEMU-KVM. Создал виртуальную машину, а подключится к ней не могу. Как подключится к виртуальной машине, у которой нет даже IP?

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-kvm-vnc-for-guest-machine/amp/

Comment: @defrag, ничего не понятно(

Comment: Не понятно, что делать, или не понятно, потому что английский?

Comment: Непонятно что делать на английском)

Comment: @defrag , не понятно что делать на английском)

Comment: https://virt-manager.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно подключаться к консоли гостевой машины с помощью VNC.
Для Libvirt надо в XML конфигурации машины добавить поддержку VNC:

```
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5987' autoport='no' listen='0.0.0.0'>
      <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
    </graphics>
```

Для голого QEMU/KVM есть ключ:

```
    -vnc 0.0.0.0:5987
```

5987 - заведомо свободный порт на данной системе.

**Внимание!** Данная конфигурация позволит подключаться к консоли с других компьютеров вашей сети. Чтобы подключаться только локально, исправьте 0.0.0.0 на 127.0.0.1

Далее с помощью любого VNC клиента можно будет подключиться к консоли этой машины, используя соответствующий адрес и порт. Рекомендую UltraVNC для Windows и Remmina для Linux.